# Aggregating a Date Range

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm struggling with creating a query to rollup a date range whilst grouping contiguously by two fields - basically I'm trying to turn this:

```
|Key|Valid|DateFrom  |DateTo    |
|  1|    0|2001-01-01|2001-01-31|
|  1|    0|2001-02-01|2001-02-20|
|  1|    1|2001-02-21|2001-02-28|
|  1|    0|2001-03-01|2001-03-15|
|  2|    1|2001-01-01|2001-01-31|
|  2|    0|2001-02-01|2001-02-20|
|  2|    0|2001-02-21|2001-02-28|
|  2|    1|2001-03-01|2001-03-15|
```

into this:

```
|Key|Valid|DateFrom  |DateTo    |
|  1|    0|2001-01-01|2001-02-20|
|  1|    1|2001-02-21|2001-02-28|
|  1|    0|2001-03-01|2001-03-15|
|  2|    1|2001-01-01|2001-01-31|
|  2|    0|2001-02-01|2001-02-28|
|  2|    1|2001-03-01|2001-03-15|
```

Naturally a simple min(DateFrom), max(DateTo) group by Key, Valid doesn't work because it doesn't respect the chronological order of the date ranges. It should be noted there are no gaps in the date ranges within each key and valid group.

I've searched far and wide for solution (both here and elsewhere on the web) and found plenty of solutions for grouping dates using OVER and CTE's (tried them both) but I think the problem is that I'm trying to factor in two different groups. I've also tried converting the ranges to individual dates but again I can't seem to roll them up chronologically by two groups.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are there ever any gaps or overlaps in your source data?

Comment: Can you use any of the offered solutions ?

Comment: Yeah now answered  - thanks to everyone for their suggestions - much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a SQL client in front of me, but you can do something like this...

```
WITH
  sequenced_data
AS
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Key        ORDER BY DateFrom) AS KeyRow,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Key, Valid ORDER BY DateFrom) AS KeyValidRow,
    *
  FROM
    yourData
)
SELECT
  Key,
  Valid,
  MIN(DateFrom) AS DateFrom,
  MAX(DatTo)    AS DateTo
FROM
  sequenced_data
GROUP BY
  Key,
  Valid,
  KeyRow - KeyValidRow
ORDER BY
  Key,
  MIN(DateFrom)
```

Visualisation with your data...

```
|Key|Valid|DateFrom  |DateTo    |KeyRow|KeyValidRow|KeyRow - KeyValidRow
|  1|    0|2001-01-01|2001-01-31|     1|          1|       0
|  1|    0|2001-02-01|2001-02-20|     2|          2|       0
|  1|    1|2001-02-21|2001-02-28|     3|          1|       2
|  1|    0|2001-03-01|2001-03-15|     4|          3|       1
|  2|    1|2001-01-01|2001-01-31|     1|          1|       0
|  2|    0|2001-02-01|2001-02-20|     2|          1|       1
|  2|    0|2001-02-21|2001-02-28|     3|          2|       1
|  2|    1|2001-03-01|2001-03-15|     4|          2|       2
```

Although `KeyRow - KeyValidRow` doesn't necessarily tell you much, it does give a distinct value for each group, and so is sufficient for the `GROUP BY`.

It works regardless of how many records there are in a group, but Does assume that there are no gaps or overlaps in the data.

Comment: (there are no gaps or overlaps)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by first calculating the key rows (ie where valid or key changes) and then link to the max date to for that group.

EDIT - Rewrite to handle the corner case marked by Dems.  This verson also deals with gaps in the sequence

```
with keyItems as ( 
  -- First find all the "Key Frames" 
  select d.* 
from  
  data d 
left outer join data d2  
  on d.[Key]=d2.[key] and d.valid=d2.valid and d.dateFrom = DateAdd(d,1,d2.dateto) 
where d2.[key] is null 
), 
ordered as ( 
  -- This is to provide a sequence number for the main query against these key frames 
  select  
    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by [key] order by datefrom) as row, 
    * 
  from keyItems 
),
rangeends([key],row,dateto) as (
select o.[key],o.row-1,MAX(d.DateTo)
from ordered o left outer join data d on d.[key]=o.[key] and d.DateTo < o.DateFrom
group by o.[key],o.row-1
union all
select o.[key],MAX(o.row),MAX(d.dateto)
from ordered o inner join data d on d.[key]=o.[key] 
group by o.[key]
)
select 
    o1.[Key], 
    o1.Valid, 
    o1.DateFrom, 
    coalesce(r.dateto,o1.dateTo) as DateTo 
    from ordered o1 
    left outer join rangeends r on r.[key]=o1.[Key] and r.row=o1.row
```

Comment: What if there are 3 or more sequential records for the same (Key,Valid) combination?

Comment: @Dems This should still work, the code finds the switch over points by locating records that do not have a directly preceding record.  And then iterates over those "Key Frames"

Comment: Sorry, my bad.  I only skimmed the query and assumed what it does - wrongly.  There is a corner case that this may not handle though...  If I added the record `|  1|    0|2001-03-16|2001-03-31|`, would the final result still show a `DateTo` value of `2001-03-15`?

Comment: I have now corrected appropriately, code will now handle the corner case and gaps in the sequence.  Overlaps are different case entirely!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't come up with anything short of using a cursor.  This does work, however:

```
declare @example table (tKey int, Valid int, DateFrom date, DateTo date);

insert into @example values (1, 0, '2001-01-01', '2001-01-31');
insert into @example values (1, 0, '2001-02-01', '2001-02-20');
insert into @example values (1, 1, '2001-02-21', '2001-02-28');
insert into @example values (1, 0, '2001-03-01', '2001-03-15');
insert into @example values (2, 1, '2001-01-01', '2001-01-31');
insert into @example values (2, 0, '2001-02-01', '2001-02-20');
insert into @example values (2, 0, '2001-02-21', '2001-02-28');
insert into @example values (2, 1, '2001-03-01', '2001-03-15');

declare @output table (tKey int, Valid int, DateFrom date, DateTo date);

DECLARE ex_cursor CURSOR FOR
    select 
        tKey,Valid,DateFrom,DateTo
    from 
        @example
    order by tKey, DateFrom

DECLARE @tKey int
DECLARE @Valid int
DECLARE @DateFrom date
DECLARE @DateTo date

DECLARE @last_tKey int
DECLARE @last_Valid int
DECLARE @min_Date date
DECLARE @max_Date date

OPEN ex_cursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM ex_cursor
INTO @tKey, @Valid, @DateFrom, @DateTo;
SET @last_tKey = @tKey;
SET @last_Valid = @Valid;
SET @min_Date = @DateFrom;
SET @max_Date = @DateTo;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF (@last_tKey <> @tKey OR @last_Valid <> @Valid)
        BEGIN
            -- output results
            INSERT INTO @output SELECT @last_tKey, @last_Valid, @min_Date, @max_Date
            -- reset values
            SET @last_tKey = @tKey;
            SET @last_Valid = @Valid;
            SET @min_Date = @DateFrom;
            SET @max_Date = @DateTo;
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            IF (@DateTo > @max_Date) SET @max_Date = @DateTo
        END
    FETCH NEXT FROM ex_cursor
    INTO @tKey, @Valid, @DateFrom, @DateTo
END 
-- output one more time at end
INSERT INTO @output SELECT @last_tKey, @last_Valid, @min_Date, @max_Date
CLOSE ex_cursor;
DEALLOCATE ex_cursor;

SELECT * FROM @output ORDER BY tKey, DateFrom
```

Comment: As implied at the start of the answer; although this does work, cursors often incur a heavy cost - If there is a set based approach, it's often worth exploring that first...